# How do you call Python code from C code?

Tags: python, c, interop, cross-domain

I want to extend a large C project with some new functionality, but I really want to write it in Python.  Basically, I want to call Python code from C code.  However, Python->C wrappers like SWIG allow for the OPPOSITE, that is writing C modules and calling C from Python.

I'm considering an approach involving IPC or RPC (I don't mind having multiple processes); that is, having my pure-Python component run in a separate process (on the same machine) and having my C project communicate with it by writing/reading from a socket (or unix pipe).  my python component can read/write to socket to communicate.  Is that a reasonable approach?  Is there something better?  Like some special RPC mechanism?

Thanks for the answer so far - **however, i'd like to focus on IPC-based approaches since I want to have my Python program in a separate process as my C program.  I don't want to embed a Python interpreter.  Thanks!**

Comment: What's your rationale for wanting to put the Python program in a separate process, and not wanting to embed a Python interpreter? I'm curious.

Comment: Well if he can get a way with just piping strings to python and then back to C when it is done it seems a lot simpler than embedding a python interpreter. Simply calling a separate python app will require 5 mins of integration if the interface is simple (just pass strings in and strings out) and I am sure embedding an interpreter will take a little longer than 5 mins

Comment: Here a complete example https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441794/5842403

where you can see embedded Python in C, and then C embedded in Systemverilog using DPI.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recommend the [approaches detailed here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497).  It starts by explaining how to execute strings of Python code, then from there details how to set up a Python environment to interact with your C program, call Python functions from your C code, manipulate Python objects from your C code, etc.

**EDIT**: If you really want to go the route of IPC, then you'll want to use [the struct module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) or better yet, [protlib](http://courtwright.org/protlib).  Most communication between a Python and C process revolves around passing structs back and forth, either [over a socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) or through [shared memory](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html).

I recommend creating a `Command` struct with fields and codes to represent commands and their arguments.  I can't give much more specific advice without knowing more about what you want to accomplish, but in general I recommend the [protlib](https://pythonhosted.org/protlib/) library, since it's what I use to communicate between C and Python programs (disclaimer: I am the author of protlib).

Comment: I've done this before and it worked out well. I had several C processes that communicated by sending structs over a socket and wanted to allow python processes too. Writing the protocol stuff was trivial in python and I was able to write a Python script that ran as part of the build to autocreate the Python code to pack/unpack the C structs by parsing the .H files. Only problem is due to all the string packing/unpacking, performance isn't nearly what you would get with native C acting directly on the binary representation of the structs just memcopy and casting the raw data off the socket.

Answer (score 9):

Have you considered just wrapping your python application in a shell script and invoking it from within your C application?

Not the most elegant solution, but it is very simple.

Comment: Indeed if he wants to run Python in a separate process and talk to it over stdin/stdio, that's just about the best solution.

Answer (score 6):

See the relevant chapter in the manual: http://docs.python.org/extending/

Essentially you'll have to embed the python interpreter into your program.

Comment: I think the link you gave talks about calling C code from python (which is opposite of what OP wants). Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used an IPC approach for Python<->C communication but it should work pretty well. I would have the C program do a standard fork-exec and use redirected `stdin` and `stdout` in the child process for the communication. A nice text-based communication will make it very easy to develop and test the Python program.

Comment: Is fork-exec possible on Windows? Not sure what the questioner's platform is.

Comment: There is a (barely) documented way to do fork-exec under Windows, but I wouldn't do it there. He mentioned unix sockets so I'm assuming that the target isn't Windows. I guess it would be more like spawn and pipe under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If I had decided to go with IPC, I'd probably splurge with [XML-RPC](http://www.xmlrpc.com/) -- cross-platform, lets you easily put the Python server project on a different node later if you want, has many excellent implementations (see [here](http://www.xmlrpc.com/directory/1568/implementations) for many, including C and Python ones, and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) for the simple XML-RPC server that's part the Python standard library -- not as highly scalable as other approaches but probably fine and convenient for your use case).

It may not be a perfect IPC approach for all cases (or even a perfect RPC one, by all means!), but the convenience, flexibility, robustness, and broad range of implementations outweigh a lot of minor defects, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This seems quite nice http://thrift.apache.org/, there is even a book about it.

Details:

> The Apache Thrift software framework, for scalable cross-language
>   services development, combines a software stack with a code generation
>   engine to build services that work efficiently and seamlessly between
>   C++, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, Erlang, Perl, Haskell, C#, Cocoa,
>   JavaScript, Node.js, Smalltalk, OCaml and Delphi and other languages.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the "standard" approach of [Embedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#embedding-python-in-another-application). But it's complicated/tedious. Each new function in Python is painful to implement.

I saw an example of [Calling PyPy from C](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/embedding.html#more-complete-example). It uses CFFI to simplify the interface but it requires PyPy, not Python. Read and understand this example first, at least at a high level.

I modified the C/PyPy example to work with Python. Here's how to call Python from C using CFFI.

My example is more complicated because I implemented three functions in Python instead of one. I wanted to cover additional aspects of passing data back and forth.

The complicated part is now isolated to passing the address of `api` to Python. That only has to be implemented once. After that it's easy to add new functions in Python.

interface.h

```
// These are the three functions that I implemented in Python.
// Any additional function would be added here.
struct API {
    double (*add_numbers)(double x, double y);
    char* (*dump_buffer)(char *buffer, int buffer_size);
    int (*release_object)(char *obj);
};
```

test_cffi.c

```
//
// Calling Python from C.
// Based on Calling PyPy from C:
// http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/embedding.html#more-complete-example
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "Python.h"

#include "interface.h"

struct API api;   /* global var */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc;

    // Start Python interpreter and initialize "api" in interface.py using 
    // old style "Embedding Python in Another Application":
    // https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#embedding-python-in-another-application
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *py_results;
    PyObject *fill_api;
#define PYVERIFY(exp) if ((exp) == 0) { fprintf(stderr, "%s[%d]: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); PyErr_Print(); exit(1); }

    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString(
            "import sys;"
            "sys.path.insert(0, '.')" );

    PYVERIFY( pName = PyString_FromString("interface") )
    PYVERIFY( pModule = PyImport_Import(pName) )
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    PYVERIFY( fill_api = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "fill_api") )

    // "k" = [unsigned long],
    // see https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue
    PYVERIFY( py_results = PyObject_CallFunction(fill_api, "k", &api) )
    assert(py_results == Py_None);

    // Call Python function from C using cffi.
    printf("sum: %f\n", api.add_numbers(12.3, 45.6));

    // More complex example.
    char buffer[20];
    char * result = api.dump_buffer(buffer, sizeof buffer);
    assert(result != 0);
    printf("buffer: %s\n", result);

    // Let Python perform garbage collection on result now.
    rc = api.release_object(result);
    assert(rc == 0);

    // Close Python interpreter.
    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

interface.py

```
import cffi
import sys
import traceback

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef(file('interface.h').read())

# Hold references to objects to prevent garbage collection.
noGCDict = {}

# Add two numbers.
# This function was copied from the PyPy example.
@ffi.callback("double (double, double)")
def add_numbers(x, y):
    return x + y

# Convert input buffer to repr(buffer).
@ffi.callback("char *(char*, int)")
def dump_buffer(buffer, buffer_len):
    try:
        # First attempt to access data in buffer.
        # Using the ffi/lib objects:
        # http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#using-the-ffi-lib-objects
        # One char at time, Looks inefficient.
        #data = ''.join([buffer[i] for i in xrange(buffer_len)])

        # Second attempt.
        # FFI Interface:
        # http://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/using.html#ffi-interface
        # Works but doc says "str() gives inconsistent results".
        #data = str( ffi.buffer(buffer, buffer_len) )

        # Convert C buffer to Python str.
        # Doc says [:] is recommended instead of str().
        data = ffi.buffer(buffer, buffer_len)[:]

        # The goal is to return repr(data)
        # but it has to be converted to a C buffer.
        result = ffi.new('char []', repr(data))

        # Save reference to data so it's not freed until released by C program.
        noGCDict[ffi.addressof(result)] = result

        return result
    except:
        print >>sys.stderr, traceback.format_exc()
        return ffi.NULL

# Release object so that Python can reclaim the memory.
@ffi.callback("int (char*)")
def release_object(ptr):
    try:
        del noGCDict[ptr]
        return 0
    except:
        print >>sys.stderr, traceback.format_exc()
        return 1

def fill_api(ptr):
    global api
    api = ffi.cast("struct API*", ptr)

    api.add_numbers = add_numbers
    api.dump_buffer = dump_buffer
    api.release_object = release_object
```

Compile:

```
gcc -o test_cffi test_cffi.c -I/home/jmudd/pgsql-native/Python-2.7.10.install/include/python2.7 -L/home/jmudd/pgsql-native/Python-2.7.10.install/lib -lpython2.7
```

Execute:

```
$ test_cffi
sum: 57.900000
buffer: 'T\x9e\x04\x08\xa8\x93\xff\xbf]\x86\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Few tips for binding it with Python 3

1. file() not supported, use open()

`ffi.cdef(open('interface.h').read())`

3. PyObject* PyStr_FromString(const char *u)

```
    Create a PyStr from a UTF-8 encoded null-terminated character buffer.
    Python 2: PyString_FromString
    Python 3: PyUnicode_FromString
```

Change to: PYVERIFY( pName = PyUnicode_FromString("interface") )

4. Program name

```
    wchar_t *name = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    Py_SetProgramName(name);
```

5. for compiling

```
   gcc cc.c -o cc -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.6m -lpython3.6m
```

6. I butchered dump def .. maybe it will give some ideas

```
def get_prediction(buffer, buffer_len):
    try:
        data = ffi.buffer(buffer, buffer_len)[:]
        result = ffi.new('char []', data)
      
        print('\n I am doing something here here........',data )

        resultA = ffi.new('char []', b"Failed")  ### New message 

        ##noGCDict[ffi.addressof(resultA)] = resultA 
        return resultA
    except:
        print >>sys.stderr, traceback.format_exc()
        return ffi.NULL
}
```

Hopefully it will help and save you some time

Answer (score 0):

apparently Python need to be able to compile to win32 dll, it will solve the problem

In such a way that converting c# code to win32 dlls will make it usable by any development tool

Comment: This only applies to win32 platform :-p  What about Unix?