# How to unpickle from C code

Tags: python, c

I have a python code computing a matrix, and I would like to use this matrix (or array, or list) from C code.
I wanted to pickle the matrix from the python code, and unpickle it from c code, but I could not find documentation or example on how to do this.
I found something about marshalling data, but nothing about unpickling from C.

Edit :
Commenters Peter H asked if I was working with numpy arrays. The answer is yes.

Comment: The best answer might depend on the specifics.  Is this a numpy array (and if not, why not?).  Will your C code being using any external libraries to work with it?  How general do you really want this to be?  I'd just dump the numpy array out "raw" and read it into a malloc'd block of memory in C, unless I had exotic requirements you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Seconding Peter Hansen -- if you use numpy, you get this basically for free, no unpickling needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just a matrix, you could just write it out as a CSV file. Look at the Python csv module for this.
http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use something more standardized, like [JSON](http://www.json.org/).   You have a JSON module in Python 2.6.  There are 6 different JSON modules for C.

You might want to use something more C-like, like the Python `struct` module.  It can build a C-compatible object directly, saving you from pickling and unpickling.  http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

Comment: Struct seems better suited to write things like ioctl, or building structs in memory. Writing a binary blob does not make it easy to debug the c code. I guess I will go with the csv or json

Answer (score 2):

[Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) are an interesting approach to serialize information in a cross-language way that's also quite compact and fast (support for C, as opposed to C++, isn't part of the protobuf package as released, but linking in some C++ code may be acceptable in some C projects, or there may be third-party implementations such as [protobuf-c](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) -- see [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns) for a list of other third-party add-ons).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the chapter on Serializing Data in Mark Pilgrim's [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython3.org/serializing.html). He states there that "The pickle protocol is Python-specific; there is no guarantee of cross-language compatibility. You probably couldn’t take the [...] pickle file you just created and do anything useful with it in Perl, PHP, Java, or any other language."

Perhaps JSON is a better alternative, also explained in that chapter.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must use pickling, you can embed Python in your C program and unpickle in C via Python.

- [A quick example from Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497)
- [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c)
- [How do you call Python code from C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056051/how-do-you-call-python-code-from-c-code)

Answer (score 0):

take a look at module `struct` ?

Answer (score 0):

Besides JSON, there are also the [**Google Protocol Buffers**](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) which have 'native' support (from Google) for Python, C++ and Java -- and a number of third-party bindings to other languages including C.