# What is the way data is stored in *.npy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm saving NumPy arrays using numpy.save function.
I want other developers to have capability to read data from those file using C language.
So I need to know,how numpy organizes binary data in file.OK, it's obvious when I'm saving array of 'i4' but what about array of arrays that contains some structures?Can't find any info in documentation

UPD :
lets say tha data is something like :

```
dt = np.dtype([('outer','(3,)<i4'),('outer2',[('inner','(10,)<i4'),('inner2','f8')])])
```

UPD2 : What about saving "dynamic" data (dtype - object)

```
import numpy as np
a = [0,0,0]
b = [0,0]
c = [a,b]
dtype = np.dtype([('Name', '|S2'), ('objValue', object)])
data = np.zeros(3, dtype)
data[0]['objValue'] = a
data[1]['objValue'] = b
data[2]['objValue'] = c
data[0]['Name'] = 'a'
data[1]['Name'] = 'b'
data[2]['Name'] = 'c'

np.save(r'D:\in.npy', data)
```

Is it real to read that thing from C?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The npy file format is documented in numpy's [NEP 1 — A Simple File Format for NumPy Arrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/067cb067cb17a20422e51da908920a4fbb3ab851/doc/neps/nep-0001-npy-format.rst).

For instance, the code

```
>>> dt=numpy.dtype([('outer','(3,)<i4'),
...                 ('outer2',[('inner','(10,)<i4'),('inner2','f8')])])
>>> a=numpy.array([((1,2,3),((10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19),3.14)),
...                ((4,5,6),((-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-20),6.28))],dt)
>>> numpy.save('1.npy', a)
```

results in the file:

```
93 4E 55 4D 50 59                      magic ("\x93NUMPY")
01                                     major version (1)
00                                     minor version (0)

96 00                                  HEADER_LEN (0x0096 = 150)
7B 27 64 65 73 63 72 27 
3A 20 5B 28 27 6F 75 74 
65 72 27 2C 20 27 3C 69 
34 27 2C 20 28 33 2C 29 
29 2C 20 28 27 6F 75 74 
65 72 32 27 2C 20 5B 28 
27 69 6E 6E 65 72 27 2C 
20 27 3C 69 34 27 2C 20 
28 31 30 2C 29 29 2C 20 
28 27 69 6E 6E 65 72 32                Header, describing the data structure
27 2C 20 27 3C 66 38 27                "{'descr': [('outer', '<i4', (3,)),
29 5D 29 5D 2C 20 27 66                            ('outer2', [
6F 72 74 72 61 6E 5F 6F                               ('inner', '<i4', (10,)), 
72 64 65 72 27 3A 20 46                               ('inner2', '<f8')]
61 6C 73 65 2C 20 27 73                            )],
68 61 70 65 27 3A 20 28                  'fortran_order': False,
32 2C 29 2C 20 7D 20 20                  'shape': (2,), }"
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 
20 20 20 20 20 0A 

01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00    (1,2,3)
0A 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00
0D 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00
10 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 12 00 00 00
13 00 00 00                            (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
1F 85 EB 51 B8 1E 09 40                3.14

04 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 06 00 00 00    (4,5,6)
FF FF FF FF FE FF FF FF FD FF FF FF
FC FF FF FF FB FF FF FF FA FF FF FF
F9 FF FF FF F8 FF FF FF F7 FF FF FF 
EC FF FF FF                            (-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-20)
1F 85 EB 51 B8 1E 19 40                6.28
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the easiest sample

Comment: What about array of arrays that contains some structures?What is the order of data in that case?In your example matrix elements are stored by rows,it's obvious, I want to know how numpy stores complicated data

Comment: @taras: See update. You should edit your question to show how complicated it goes (the sample data) if that's still not complicated enough.

Comment: updated my question,added type example.What's the rule?All the data is stored sequentially?

Comment: @taras: Yes sequentially. "... the data is the
    contiguous (either C- or Fortran-, depending on fortran_order)
    bytes of the array."

Comment: made final update.with "object" dtype, it's most interesting situation

Comment: @taras: "If the dtype contains
    Python objects (i.e. `dtype.hasobject is True`), then the data is
    a Python pickle of the array."

Comment: So it's impossible to read from C code?I mean does exist any way to locate bytes of that object and read them?

Comment: @taras: You can read from C code, but you need to unpickle it in C. Why you do need to store something like this? numpy isn't designed as a generic database.

Comment: So i need some tool to unpickle it from C?                              Why i need to use it?...I'm making a decision know, so need to know how to do/is it possible...

Comment: @taras: You may check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881851/how-to-unpickle-from-c-code/1882086#1882086

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Now I'll think twice before making decision use or not numpy in this way...

Comment: The URL for npy-format doesn't work anymore.
The new URL is: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/npy-format.txt

Comment: Neither original nor "new" link by @BjarkeEbert works nowadays. Can't find the documentation by Googling (lots of broken links.) Anyone with an update?

Comment: @BmyGuest Changed to a permalink.

Answer (score 6):

The format is described in [numpy/lib/format.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/format.py), where you can also see the Python source code used to load npy files. `np.load` is defined [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/npyio.py).