# How to import numpy array into swift Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, numpy

I have some 2-dimensional data of shape (1024, 4) that is stored as an array to a binary file in NumPy `.npy` format.

```
arr = np.array(<some >)
arr.shape
# >>> (1024, 4)

np.save(fileName, arr)
# >>> .../SomeData.npy
```

How can I import this data into a Swift Array? It would have helped me if the data were read column by column.

Finally I want to have something like this:

```
let imported : [Float] = ???
```

Comment: Maybe you can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090080/what-is-the-way-data-is-stored-in-npy)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a good starting point to write my own data import routine.