# Merge multiple large float32 matrices into one and store them

Tags: python, matrix, large-data

I am trying to merge 34 matrices each sized `256 x 6000000` and of type `numpy.float32` into a single matrix and store it on my system. Each matrix is stored in a separate `.npy` file.

**This is the script I am using:**

```
import numpy as np
import os

# combined matrix variable
amp_data = []
count=0
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith('.npy'):
    if count==0:
        amp_data = np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r')   
    else:
        amp_ = np.load(filename, mmap_mode='r')
        amp_data = np.hstack((amp_data, amp_))
        del amp_
    count = count+1
```

My system runs into memory error obviously (RAM: 64Gb). Is there way for me to combine these matrices into one and save them?

Comment: If the arrays are too large to combine and save, then they are also too large to use in any meaningful way, right?

Comment: This doesn't get around the ultimate memory error, but the recommended way of combining arrays is to collect them in a list (`amp_data.append(amp_)`, and then using concatenate (or one of the `stack`) to create one file in one step.  It's more efficient then repeated `hstack`.

Comment: the reason I am trying to merge this into a single file is that another analysis software that I am currently using can load large files without running into memory overflow error.

Comment: Would the other system be happy working with `HDF5` files?  I have used it much, but with `h5py` you can define a file and dataset that can grow along one dimension.  That is mentioned in one of the linked answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The npy format is documented at [NEP 1 — A Simple File Format for NumPy Arrays](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0001-npy-format.rst). It is intented to be easily reverse engineered or directly processed by other programs.

So you should be able to read on file at a time and write it directly into a larger npy file.

---

References:

> Requirements
>   The format MUST be able to:
> ...
>   A competent developer should be able to create a solution in his preferred programming language to read most NPY files...

You will find additional examples and references in [What is the way data is stored in *.npy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4090080/3545273)

You could even find reusable code in [numpy/format.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/format.py).