# Why does tf.read_file() and tf.decode_raw() change size?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want to upload an npy file to tensor. So I used `tf.decode_raw()` after `tf.read_file()`, but the value and size are **different** from the original npy file. Can't improve this? ( I know it works with `tf.convert_to_tensor()`, but I think I should use `read_file()` to do `tf.train.slice_input_producer()` for running deep learning. )

```py
file_reader = tf.read_file('./data/test_LR/T2_npy/T2_168_C6M5_1.npy')
ab = tf.decode_raw(file_reader, out_type = tf.uint8)
sess = tf.Session()
a = sess.run(ab)
print(np.shape(a))

# result
(49280,)
```

```py
an = np.load('./data/test_LR/T2_npy/T2_168_C6M5_1.npy')
print(np.shape(an))

# result
(192,256) -> 49152
```

Comment: My guess is that `npy` files store a header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the way data is stored in \*.npy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090080/what-is-the-way-data-is-stored-in-npy)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889482/feeding-npy-numpy-files-into-tensorflow-data-pipeline

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice!! It works well and have a nice day :)