# python to c transition

Tags: python, c

I am Python programmer and now I thinking to learn C language. But there are things are that not good with C. 
First of all, trying new code in C a long process whereas in Python you just have to open shell interpreter and can write whatever code you want and see output instantly. 
So is there way to reduce this lot of saving, compiling and watching output cycle of C language?

Comment: Using good IDE like Visual Studio can go a long way toward minimizing the pain of compiling/running/debugging your C code...

Comment: @theAlse so where should I go. I tried googling it but won't find an effective way. do you have any way out of it.

Comment: @Jarvish, this might be a good place to start. https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you call Python code from C code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056051/how-do-you-call-python-code-from-c-code)

Comment: If I remember correctly, the ROOT tool (http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) had a decent interactive C++ interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do for yourself in this regard (cutting down on the pain of incremental testing during development) is learn how to use the GNU make utility. A reasonable introduction to the utility can be found here: [Makefile Tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/). The example in the tutorial uses C++ files with the g++ compiler, but you can substitute gcc or any other C compiler (or, really, any compiler for any language).