# Static python build missing modules

Tags: python, c, module, static-linking

I recently needed a static version of python in one of my projects, so i got the source and built it. After linking it to my application when I run it I am missing all of the required modules and I don't know where to put them.

Errors:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named time
```

Code:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                 "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}

Code for building exe:

```
gcc main.c -I/Desktop/Python-2.6.4 -I//Desktop/Python-2.6.4/Include -I/Desktop/Python-2.6.4/Modules -L/Desktop/Python-2.6.4 -lpython2.6 -static
```

[Tutorial for building python statically](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically)

If someone could tell me where to put these modules or even better tell me how to link them statically, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an answer to your question, but I would suggest trying a portable Python distribution like these:

- https://www.egenix.com/products/python/PyRun/
- http://portablepython.com/ (Windows)
- http://www.pyzo.org/index.html
- http://www.pythonxy.com/
- https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

Some of them are geared towards scientific computing, but especially pyrun or portablepython should provide you with a small package.

There are even more options, maybe one of them solves your problem.

Comment: im not sure about the portable python install, because it is huge. The installiation itself is roughly 250mb, I just need the modules included which is roughly 20mb. I'll consider it but i don't think i can implement this in such a small app. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve in the end? You are on Windows, right? Maybe building an executable with py2exe or another solution (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/) could work? You should be able to include only modules that your application needs.

Comment: I just installed PortablePython in Wine, after deselecting all the modules the size was down to 50MB. I think if you delete everything that isn't needed (you can use https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/modulefinder.html to see which modules you have to include) you should be able to bring the size down much further. If you just want to ship a python project I would check the freezing solutions.

Comment: I want to be able to view and execute python code directly from C code without the user having to have python installed. I don't think I could achieve this from freezing?

Comment: Ah, in this case I think you are right and freezing is not going to help you. I don't think I can help you with that problem, maybe you will find something useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1056057/204706
Best of luck!