# How to Run Python Script from C?

Tags: python, c

Does anybody know how to run a python script from C?

Basically, I'm trying to make it so that when I press a button connected to my arduino, my arduino, which is connected to my raspberry pi 3B+, will run a python script which takes a photo.

Does anybody know how to pull this off? Also, is there any simpler, easier way to do it? I don't know how to use the GPIO on raspberry pi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you call Python code from C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056051/how-do-you-call-python-code-from-c-code)

Comment: Are you trying to call python on the pi from C code on the Arduino, to call python on the pi from C code on the pi, or run python code on the Arduino from C code also on the Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have python installed you can just use the [`system()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function and just call python directly, if you want more control like capturing program's output or giving input, and more interaction [`popen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) is available for Arduino.

Otherwise if you can link to the python library just use [`PyRun_SimpleString(code);`](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497). The previous link has an example of how you need to setup the environment before actually calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

`system()` allows you to call anything in python. [This link](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497) goes into more depth if you want to interact with input or output.

A really simple way to run any python script is to wrap it in a shell script and invoke it from within your C application

For more info, view the docs: ([1](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/), [2](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ext/callingPython.html))